# Good practice for "ref" arguments and nullable checking

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

What's the best approach to follow when I face situations like the following?

The context is a .NET Core 3.x application with the latest [nullable checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) enabled, and a method with the `ref` keyword. The real code is more complex, but a simpler version could be this:

```
private static bool _initialized = false;
private static object _initializationLock = new object();
private static MyClass _initializationTarget;  //suggestion to mark as nullable

public MyClass GetInstance()
{
    return LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(
        ref _initializationTarget,
        ref _initialized,
        ref _initializationLock,
        () => new MyClass()
        );
}
```

The [`EnsureInitialized()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer.ensureinitialized?view=netcore-3.1) method takes the `_initializationTarget` reference, which is `null` at the beginning, and hence marking it as nullable seems the correct adjustment. However, the same method ensures the variable to be properly filled.

I couldn't find a better pattern than the following—but is it really the best one?

```
private static bool _initialized = false;
private static object _initializationLock = new object();
private static MyClass? _initializationTarget;  //marked as nullable

public MyClass GetInstance()
{
    //the return value must also nullable
    MyClass? inst = LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(
        ref _initializationTarget,
        ref _initialized,
        ref _initializationLock,
        () => new MyClass()
        );

    return inst!;  //null-forgive here
}
```

Comment: Could you share method `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized`?

Comment: That's part of the standard library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer.ensureinitialized?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: In my opinion your approach is the best in this case. At first, by declaring field `_initializationTarget` as a nullable reference type you implicitly express that it can contain `null` value. It makes compiler being able to detect its usages where it can be null. For example, if you declare another method that uses `_initializationTarget` without checking if it is `null`. At second, method `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` is not guaranteed to return `non-null` value. It can return `null` is several cases, for example, if `_initialized` is `true` and `_initializationTarget` is `null`.

Comment: But in your case you know for sure that `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` must return `non-null` value because provided arguments guarantee that the return value will not be `null`. Code analyzer is not smart enough to identify that in your case `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` guarantees that the result is not null. Therfore to satisfy code analyzer you have to use `null-forgiving operator`.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev: It’s not well-documented, but there _are_ actually overloads of `EnsureEnabled()` that are annotated with `[NotNull]` instead of `[MaybeNull]`—and thus _will_ assure the compiler that the `target` reference is no longer `null` after execution. In those cases, the null-forgiving operator isn’t needed. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn’t include the nullability attributes, and the remarks fail to highlight that nuance. I’ve expanded on this in my answer, along with links to the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If you remove the `initialized` argument, then `EnsureInitialized()` will guarantee that the returned object is [`[NotNull]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#specify-post-conditions-maybenull-and-notnull)—even if you pass in an unitialized `MyClass?` reference—and thus there won't be a need to use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) (`!`).

---

## Complete Answer

This is a good question. The answer to your *specific* example is really easy, but I also want to take the opportunity to address your *general* question regarding how to handle `ref` arguments with C# 8.0's nullable reference types. In doing so, that will not only help address other scenarios like this, but also offer an explanation of *why* the solution to your specific example works.

### Specific Example

While [the `EnsureInitialized()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer.ensureinitialized?view=netcore-3.1) doesn't make this entirely clear, the particular overload you are calling is for situations where you potentially *want* a `null` target. Namely, if you were to instead pass a value of `true` for the `initialized` parameter, then it would return `null`. That condition is why it *must* return a nullable type.

Since you *don't* want to permit `null` values—and aren't working with a value type—you simply need to remove the `initialized` argument. You'll still need to declare your `_initializationTarget` as nullable, since it isn't being initialized in your constructor. This overload, however, guarantees to the compiler that the `target` parameter will no longer be `null` after `EnsureInitialized()` has run:

```cs
private static object _initializationLock = new object();
private static MyClass? _initializationTarget;  //marked as nullable

public MyClass GetInstance() =>
    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(
        ref _initializationTarget,
        ref _initializationLock,
        () => new MyClass()
    );
```

Notice that while it still passes in a null(able) `MyClass?`, it confidently returns a `MyClass` without needing to resort to the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) (`!`).

### General Question

As you dive further into C# 8.0's nullable reference types, you'll discover a number of gaps in Roslyn's static flow analysis which cannot be disambiguated by simply using the `?` and `!` operators alone. Fortunately, Microsoft foresaw this problem and provided us with a variety of [attributes which can be used to provide compiler hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis).

#### Example

Here's a basic example to illustrate the general problem:

```cs
public void EnsureNotNull(ref Object? input) => input ??= new Object();
```

If you call this method with the following code, you'll get a `CS8602` warning:

```cs
Object? object = null;
EnsureNotNull(ref object);
_ = object.ToString(); //CS8602; Dereference of a possibly null reference
```

You can mitigate this, however, by applying the [`[NotNull]` hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#specify-post-conditions-maybenull-and-notnull) to the `input` parameter:

```cs
public void EnsureNotNull([NotNull]ref Object? input) => input ??= new Object();
```

Now, any references to `object` after `EnsureNotNull()` is called will be known (by the compiler) to not be `null`.

### `EnsureInitialized()` overloads

If you evaluate [the source code for `LazyInitializer`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/LazyInitializer.cs#L245) with the above in mind, the answer to your specific problem becomes a lot more clear. The [overload you were calling](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/LazyInitializer.cs#L197) marks `target` as `[AllowNull]`, which is the equivalent to returning `MyClass?`:

```cs
public static T EnsureInitialized<T>([AllowNull] ref T target, ref bool initialized, [NotNull] ref object? syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory) => …
```

By contrast, [the overload that I've recommended](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/LazyInitializer.cs#L245) implements the `[NotNull]` attribute discussed above, which is the equivalent of returning `MyClass`:

```cs
public static T EnsureInitialized<T>([NotNull] ref T? target, [NotNull] ref object? syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory) where T : class => …
```

If you evaluate the actual logic, you'll see they're basically the same, except the former includes an escape clause for the scenario where `initialized` is `true`—and, therefore, allows `target` to potentially remain `null`.

Since you *know* that you're working with a class and *don't* want a `null` value, however, the latter overload is the best choice, and implements the exact practice outlined in my answer to your general question.

Comment: excellent answer, should be part of the official documentation! I still have little practice with nullables, and I totally skipped (for the moment) some code sections involving generics.